# What is the grammatical function of "never"?

Tags: terminology, adverbs, negation, parts-of-speech

What is the grammatical function of "never" in the following sentence?

> You will have to do something you've *never* done.

Is it an adverb? My father disagrees with this.

In "I have studied" vs. "I have *not* studied" and "I have done" vs. "I have *never* done", the *not* and *never* have the same function, as stated by my father. He says it has something to do with disagreeing. But he doesn't know the grammatical term for the structure.

Can someone tell me the specific grammatical term, if there is one? If it is an adverb, is it a specific type?

Comment: Yes, it is an adverb

Comment: *Not* and *never* are both adverbs.

Comment: _Not_ is often an adverb, and _never_ usually is; but _not_ has lots of other functions as well, e.g, _Not this August, nor this September_. Both words are [Negatives](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/NPIs.pdf).

Comment: So how to you refer them to as? "Negative adverbs"?

I know that Everyone, Everything.. etc are universals,

Someone, Something..etc are assertive,

Anyone, Anything..etc are non-assertive,

and that no one, nothing..etc are negatives but didn't know *never* can be considered negatives..

Comment: @JohnLawler: I know you take a dim view of restrictive labeling when it comes to parts of speech, but in your example aren't those negatives still adverbs for something that is implied but not stated? E.g., *[You may be sure that I cannot fail:] not this August, nor this September.*

Comment: Any words can be labelled as "adverbs for something that is implied but not stated", if one has a fertile enough imagination to reconstruct what isn't stated. Occam's Razor prohibits multiplying pluralities without necessity.

Comment: Quick note: if you rewrite the sentence as "You will have to do something you've _rarely_ done", does your father agree _rarely_ is an adverb?

Answer (score 10):

*Never* is a negative [time adverb](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/3-Time.pdf) meaning *'not at any time'*, but *no/not* (variant combining forms) is a much more versatile and important chunk of English. *Not* is just one of the forms it uses when it's a separate word, instead of existing combined in a compound or contraction.

It's the basic [Negation](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/CELS-Negation.pdf) marker in English. So it can be adjective and adverb, but mostly it's fused into phrases and contractions, of which *never* is one. *Never* is a contraction of *no/not* + *ever*, just like other contractions of *no/not*:

- *never = not ever*
- *none = not one*
- *neither = not either*
- *nor = not or*
- *no way*
- *nowhere*
- *nobody*
- *no one*
- *nothing*

There are corresponding contractions with the Negative Polarity Item *any*, like:

- *anyway*
- *anywhere*
- *anybody*
- *anyone*
- *anything*

which are Negative Polarity Items, like *ever*. 
*Ever* means what **anywhen* would mean, if there were an English word **anywhen* that was as commonly used as *anywhere*; in the same way, *both of them* means what **all two of them* would mean, if that phrase weren't ungrammatical.

More important, as a [Negative Polarity Item](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/NPIs.pdf), *ever* can **only** occur within the scope of a Negative Trigger (or, as in *never*, bonded morphologically to its trigger).

Thus, *ever* is fine in these 3 sentences, with Negative Triggers *(has)n't, few,* and *doubt*,

- *He hasn't ever seen it. ~ Few people have ever seen it. ~ I doubt he's ever seen it.*

but it makes the corresponding affirmative sentences ungrammatical, though they're OK without *ever*:

- **He has ever seen it.* ~ **A few people have ever seen it.* ~ **I think he's ever seen it.*

Comment: So is *some* a Negative Polarity Item then as well (someone, somewhere, something, somebody, some way, etc.)?

Comment: No. _Some_ is not constrained by negative polarity. That's one of the reasons why there can't be any _some/any_ rule.

Answer (score 2):

The exact label/category that you ascribe to a word depends on the purpose of your analysis. Usually the purpose of that analysis to assign words with similar broad features to the same category.

From that point of view, when used for "sentential" negation, *never* and *not* differ in an important way: "not" in reality occupies a 'special' position in the sentence and has special morphological behaviour, whereas "never" is much closer in its behaviour to a "normal" adverb. Consider:

> He **typically** comes at 6 o'clock.
>
> He **never** comes at 6 o'clock.
>
> *He **not** comes at 6 o'clock.

So as a starting point, a crude categorisation would be to say that "never", but not "not", is an adverb.

One further subcategorisation you could make is to say that "never" is specifically a type of adverb that is associated "close to the verb phrase" syntactically. In other words, it can't typically be an adjunct to broader units (such as the whole sentence), unlike other adverbs:

> He will undoubtedly/never be late.
>
> He undoubtedly/never will be late.
>
> BUT: Undoubtedly/*never, he will be late.

So one term for this type of adverb is to call it a "VP-adverb", in other words, an adverb that is associated with the verb phrase.